# Using LuaLaTeX in TeXworks

Tags: luatex, texworks

I have a template I need to use that compiles best with LuaLaTeX in TeXworks. I downloaded TeXworks and tried to select LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX from the drop-down menu, but it won't let me select anything else. Do I somehow need to install LuaLaTeX? How do I do that?

Note: I'm using Windows. I have no idea how to install or compile things in command line. So I would really appreciate instructions for someone who doesn't know how to do that.

Comment: Before you worry about TeXworks configuration, can you tell us how you installed LaTeX? There are mostly two distributions. TeX Live installs everything by default so you should have LuaLaTeX already, but MikTeX doesn't. If you're using the latter, check with its installation tool whether LuaLaTeX is installed or not.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I just went to https://sourceforge.net/projects/texworks.mirror/ and downloaded and installed. I did nothing other than that.

Comment: I wasn't asking about your editor, I was asking about LaTeX. It's just like any programming language, you have to install the language on one side, and an editor on the other. How did you install LaTeX itself?

Comment: TeXworks is a front end to a TeX distribution, but not a TeX distribution in its own right. Which TeX distribution - TeXLive, MikTeX, something else? -- is installed on your system?